# Increasing threatened area with ranged weapons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, opportunity-attack, gunslinger

In our Pathfinder campaign, my character is a Musket Master [Gunslinger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/gunslinger). I've been training towards [Improved] Snap Shot and wanted to know how to increase my **ranged** threatened area further.

I know there's a bunch of items and maneuvers for melee range, such as the Long Arm spell, the Lunge feat, Pliant Gloves, or Longarm Bracers, but I want to shoot things.

It seems that [Combat Patrol](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-patrol-combat) could increase my ranged threatened area to a 15' radius, but only at the cost of a full-round action *every turn* plus *four* feats.

Can I increase my ranged threatened area past 10' radius without incurring the awful costs of Combat Patrol?
Alternately, can I move the center of my ranged threatened area? (perhaps an overwatch position to support one of the melee characters)

Comment: Note that Combat Patrol only costs 3 feats (itself + Mobility + Combat Reflexes), and you really want one of those (Combat Reflexes) if you care at all about AoO anyway.

Comment: Mobility itself requires Dodge, although you're right about Combat Reflexes, so it's 4 on paper but 3 in effect. I'm actually more concerned about a full-round action every round to activate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any better choices than Snap Shot and Combat Patrol in offical Paizo sources, but we did find some in a 3rd party source published on the SRD.

[Threaten Zone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/louis-porter-jr-design/general-feats---3rd-party---louis-porter-jr/threaten-zone) allows you to threaten AOO and flanking with a ranged weapon in a 20' radius. It does requires +9 BAB and five prerequisite feats ([Last Ditch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/louis-porter-jr-design/general-feats---3rd-party---louis-porter-jr/last-ditch), Combat Reflexes, Point-Blank Shot, Rapid Shot, and Quick Draw).

Three of those prerequisites you'd want anyway, so there's only two "feat tax".

Improved Threatened Zone requires +15BAB and increases the range by 10' (to 30' radius).

At that point it *might* be worth it to take Combat Patrol - paying two more "feat tax" - one would threaten a 45' radius around you, which is [quite a lot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akyTH.jpg).